# How to Maintain Each Level for 5 seconds Before Going to Next Level in Android Studio (Java)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, game-development

I currently new learner and required to do a simple tapping game with Android Studio (Java) and I encounter some difficulty and need help from your guys to guide me. I have no idea how to use and where to place Timer timer.schedule() to maintain each level for 5 seconds before it move to next level and how to create a dialog message for player to click continue button before moving to next level? Below are the code attachment, thank you.

**MainActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.example.adapter.OMauAdapter;
import com.example.dialog.EndGameDialog;
import com.example.object.Defination;
import com.example.object.OMau;
import com.example.object.PlayerInfo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Defination defination = new Defination();
    ArrayList<OMau> arrOMau = new ArrayList<>();
    GridView gdvListOMau;
    OMauAdapter adapter;
    TextView textViewLevel;
    TextView textViewTime;
    TextView textViewStarCoin;
    PlayerInfo info;
    CountDownTimer countdown;
    // continue running when clicked, stop if unclick
    CountDownTimer countdown_effect;
    ImageView image;
    int iconImage = R.drawable.icon1;
    boolean jumping_cat = true;
    RelativeLayout side_layout;
    int iconSide = R.drawable.icon1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // initialization
        init();
        viewInitialization();
        setUp();
        setClick();
    }
    private void init() {
        info = new PlayerInfo(this);
        info.getData();
        sample();
        adapter = new OMauAdapter(this, 0, arrOMau);
    }
    // Get  list  view of the column
    private void viewInitialization() {
        gdvListOMau = findViewById(R.id.gdvLisOMau);
        textViewLevel = findViewById(R.id.txvLevel);
        textViewTime = findViewById(R.id.txvTime);
        image = findViewById(R.id.image);
        side_layout = findViewById(R.id.side_layout);
        textViewStarCoin = findViewById(R.id.txvStarCoin);
    }
    // set the column into seven row
    private void setUp() {
        textViewStarCoin.setText("" + info.start_coin_amount);
        gdvListOMau.setNumColumns(defination.row);
        gdvListOMau.setAdapter(adapter);
        textViewLevel.setText("" + defination.level);
        updateTime();
        countdown_effect = new CountDownTimer(2000, 200) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                if (jumping_cat == true) {
                    if (iconImage == R.drawable.icon2) {
                        iconImage = R.drawable.icon1;
                    } else {
                        iconImage = R.drawable.icon2;
                    }
                    image.setImageResource(iconImage);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                jumping_cat = false;
                if (defination.end_of_the_game == false) {
                    start();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
    private void running_countdown_effect() {
        countdown_effect.cancel();
        countdown_effect.start();
    }
    // keep on changing the highlighted view after clicking on initial one
    private void setClick() {
        gdvListOMau.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                checkColor(arrOMau.get(i));
            }
        });
    }
    // check the right highlighted color in the color boxes to be clicked
    private void checkColor(OMau o) {
        if (o.color.equals(defination.colorListTone)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            defination.level++;
            sample();
            update();
            defination.totalTime = defination.totalTime + defination.time;
            countdown.cancel();
            updateTime();
            jumping_cat = true;
            running_countdown_effect();
            info.start_coin_amount = info.start_coin_amount + 2;
            textViewStarCoin.setText("" + info.start_coin_amount);
            // call function to check whether the data is exist or not
            info.setData();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    // trace function to colour it (taoMau)
    private void sample() {
        defination.setLevel();
        // get the initial random color and display the changes accordingly
        defination.colorSampling();
        arrOMau.clear();
        while (arrOMau.size() < defination.row2) {
            arrOMau.add(new OMau(defination.colorList));
        }
        // random pick up position and change one of the position view into different colour
        Random r = new Random();
        arrOMau.get(r.nextInt(arrOMau.size())).color = defination.colorListTone;
    }
    // update the colour clip on the screen
    private void update() {
        // call update function and pass in the array and colour
        adapter.update(arrOMau);
        gdvListOMau.setNumColumns(defination.row);
        textViewLevel.setText("" + defination.level);
    }
    private void updateTime() {
        countdown = new CountDownTimer(defination.totalTime, 1) {
            // count each time when you come from the limit
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                defination.totalTime = (int) l;
                if (defination.totalTime >= 0) {
                    int second = defination.totalTime / 1000;
                    int second2 = defination.totalTime % 1000 / 10;
                    String times = second + ":" + second2;
                    textViewTime.setText(times);
                } else {
                    textViewTime.setText("00:00");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textViewTime.setText("00:00");
                timeOut();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    private void timeOut() {
        defination.end_of_the_game = true;
        gdvListOMau.setOnItemClickListener(null);
        new EndGameDialog(this, defination.level).show();
    }
}
```

**Defination**

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Defination {
    // declare all required variables
    public int row = 5;
    public int row2 = 7;
    public String colorList = "#FF0000";
    public String colorListTone = "#FA5858";
    public int level = 1;
    public int timeRun = 5;
    public int totalTime = timeRun * 1000;
    public int time = 300;
    public boolean end_of_the_game = false;
    private String arrColorList[] = new String[]{
            "#FF0000",
            "#FFFF00",
            "#3ADF00",
            "#0174DF",
            "#0101DF",
            "#A901DB",
            "#FF0040",
    };
    private String arrColorListTone[] = new String[]{
            "#FA5858",
            "#F3F781",
            "#ACFA58",
            "#2ECCFA",
            "#5858FA",
            "#D0A9F5",
            "#F7819F",
    };
    // create another row
    public void colorSampling() {
        Random r = new Random();
        // randomly take index number (position) of the color list
        int vt = r.nextInt(arrColorList.length);
        colorList = arrColorList[vt];
        colorListTone = arrColorListTone[vt];
    }
    public void setLevel() {
        if (level < 2) {
            row = 2;
        } else if (level < 3) {
            row = 3;
        } else if (level < 4) {
            row = 4;
        } else if (level < 5) {
            row = 5;
        } else if (level < 6) {
            row = 6;
        } else if (level < 7) {
            row = 7;
        } else {
            row = 8;
        }
        row2 = row * row;
    }
}
```

**OmauAdpater**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.example.object.ImgCustom;
import com.example.object.OMau;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OMauAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OMau> {
    private Context ct;
    private ArrayList<OMau> arrOMau;

    public OMauAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<OMau> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.ct = context;
        this.arrOMau = new ArrayList<>(objects);
    }

    public void update(ArrayList<OMau> arr) {
        // delete the colour box that being displayed
        this.arrOMau.clear();
        // added the data back to it
        this.arrOMau.addAll(arr);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrOMau.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ct.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_o_mau, null);
        }
        // change the color
        if (arrOMau.size() > 0) {
            OMau o = arrOMau.get(position);
            ImgCustom imgCustom = convertView.findViewById((R.id.imgOmau));
            imgCustom.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(o.color));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```